# $.get is returning "[object Document]" in iPhone simulator with PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator

I'm trying to do a simple `$.get()` request on a local file in my (XCode) iPhone simulator (using PhoneGap), but the result keeps returning as "`[object Document]`" (via alert), instead of the actual content of the file.

However, when I test it in Google Chrome, I have no issues at all. The odd thing is that I can `$.load()` the local page with no problem (in the iPhone simulator), but when I try to `$.get()` it, it wont work.

Here is my `index.html` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="load"></div>

<script>

    $.get('content/view/images.html', function(data) {

        alert(data); // returns "[object Document]"

    });

    $('.load').load('content/view/images.html'); // returns actual file content

</script>
```

Here is my `content/view/images.html` code:

```
<img src="http://static.example.com/images/{$file_key}.{$file_type}" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 200px;" />
```

However, when I change the content of `content/view/images.html` to a something like `LOL`, it will properly `$.get()` it.

Any ideas as to what in the world is going on?

Comment: `alert()` is not a proper debugging tool. It can only display strings, so anything else is converted to a string representation that might or might not be useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you tell jQuery otherwise, it will guess what to do with the data coming back on the basis of the MIME type sent back with the data. If you're getting back a document, the MIME type coming back must be XML (so presumably your HTML page is **X**HTML, or at least that's what the server's saying). (See the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation on the `dataType` option; the only time jQuery creates a document is when dealing with XML.)

You can tell jQuery you always want it as text by giving it a `dataType`, which is the argument just after the success handler in [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('content/view/images.html', function(data) {

    alert(data);

}, "text");
// ^--- new bit
```

...or you can specify it on an options object with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'content/view/images.html',
    dataType: "text",        // <=== new bit
    success: function(data) {

        alert(data);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'content/view/images.html',
  success: function(data) { alert(data); },
  dataType: "text"
});
```